# Concatenation, multiple parameters or sprintf?

Tags: php, optimization

I am working to optimize my PHP code and found out that you can speed up echoing in these ways - exactly, you can replace `echo "The name of the user is $name" . ".";` with:

- `echo 'The name of the user is '.$name.'.';`
- `echo "The name of the user is", $name, ".";`
- `echo sprintf("The name of the user is %s", $name);`

Which one is the fastest? I'd like not only to see benchmarks, but also some technical explaination, if possible.

Comment: And you haven't found that echoing a list of arguments (separated by commas) is picoseconds faster than echoing a series of values concatenated with a dot?

Comment: This really is micro-optimisation; have you already optimised all the really expensive elements in your script?

Comment: Benchmark it and you know it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Firstly, this is micro optimization and you're probably better paying for a faster server and developing more product then spending hours and hours micro optimizing. However according to http://micro-optimization.com/ here are the results:

> sprintf() is slower than double quotes by 138.68% (1.4 times slower)

and

> sprintf() is slower than single quotes by 163.72% (1.6 times slower)

Comment: Agreed with this answer. As for double and single quotes and the concatenation operator I would simply recommend using a standardized approach that suits your code style.

Comment: Also meaning, single quotes are superior to double quotes by 14%.

Comment: I already disliked sprintf() because I think it obfuscates. I'm glad to see that my preferred method is faster as well.

Comment: 1. incorrect results provided (micro-optimization.com's fault)
2. incorrect conclusion on the single/double quotes, the first 2 versions provided are behaving differently, `echo 'The name of the user is '.$name.'.';` is creating a unique string which is echoed, `echo "The name of the user is", $name, ".";` is using the "echo" keyword once, but this is a shorthand for calling echo 3 times, respectively with the arguments
3. "echo" behaves differently depending on the SAPI (cli, apache, fcgi,...) used

Answer (score 3):

The above comments are relevant. There are better ways to optimize your code.

That said, the best ways to optimize strings is to pop them into a list and then concatenation the list. Have a look at [this post](http://www.sitepoint.com/high-performance-string-concatenation-in-php/) as a good starting point.

Answer (score 3):

The variation using `sprintf()` is quite sure the slowest of all since function calls in PHP are quite expensive and `sprintf()` will have to parse the format string. Using something like `echo "abc ", $n, " xyz";` actually compiles to three single `ZEND_ECHO` opcodes, which means that the output layer is called multiple times which can be quite slow, depending on the SAPI used. It doesn't make a lot of difference whether you are using `echo "abc $n xyz";` or `echo "abc " . $n . " xyz";` since they both compile to cocatenation operations.