# PHP email progam

Tags: php, html, forms, email

Hello PHP and web enthusiasts,
I am having a problem with my php code when making a simple email page.
The error i am getting is  syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier on line 19.
Here is my code. I've been trying to fix it for days.

```
   <html>
    <h1> Contact Form </h1>
    <form action ="HW2-4.php?action=send"method="POST">
    <p> Name: <input type="text" name="name" /></p>
    <p>Email: <input type="text" name="email" /></p>
    <p>Subject: <input type="text" name="subject" /></p> 
    <p>Message: <textarea col="20" row="5" name="message" ></textarea></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Send Email"/> 
   <?php
if(isset($_POST['action']) and $_POST['action'] == "send"){
    $name    = $_POST["name"];
    $email   = $_POST["email"];
    $subject = $_POST["subject"];
    $message = $_POST["message"];
    $headers = $_POST["headers"];

    if (mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers) == 1) {
        echo "<h3>Hello ".$_POST['name']." An email has been sent to you at ".$_POST['email']."!</h3>";
    }
}
```

The page loads, but the echo statement is not showing up after email is sent and i dont think the email is sending.

Comment: `isset($_POST['action']) == "send"`, what do you expect this to do?

Comment: Why did you edit the question to contain code that is correct? Now the question doesn't make sense. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

That is because the `$_POST['name']` and `$_POST['email']` variables are not parsed properly. You should concatenate them instead, which is personally my way to inject variables into strings (although there are other alternatives), i.e:

```
echo "<h3>Hello ".$_POST['name']." An email has been sent to you at ".$_POST['email']."!</h3>";
```

In fact, simply drop the use of double quotes instead:

```
echo '<h3>Hello '.$_POST['name'].' An email has been sent to you at '.$_POST['email'].'!</h3>';
```

You can also check out the [various ways](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) how strings are parsed, which means these are also valid. With regards to *which* is better [falls within the domain of micro-optimisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17012284/concatenation-multiple-parameters-or-sprintf), as the difference between any of them can be considered insignificant compared to other operations the server is tasked with.

Method 1: **use `{}`**:

```
echo "<h3>Hello {$_POST['name']} An email has been sent to you at {$_POST['email']}!</h3>";
```

---

Method 2: or **drop the use of `'` entirely**:

```
echo "<h3>Hello $_POST[name] An email has been sent to you at $_POST[email]!</h3>";
```

---

Method 3 (suggested by [@Blowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/582278/blowski)): **use `sprintf()`**:

```
sprintf('<h3>Hello %s. An email has been sent to you at %s!</h3>', $_POST['name'], $_POST['email']);
```

Method 4: Make a variable (you already have them in this case)

```
echo "<h3>Hello $name. An email has been sent to you at $email!</h3>"
```

Comment: Or use `sprintf('<h3>Hello %s. An email has been sent to you at %s!</h3>', $_POST['name'], $_POST['email'])`, which I personally find much more readable.

Comment: His condition is also wrong, see Sumit's answer and consider adding that solution as well

Comment: @Blowski Oh yes, I have totally forgotten about that. Thanks for the heads up, and also included your comment in my updated answer (with credits appropriately given)

Comment: Won't method two cause a warning because it converts the undefined constant into a string?